# Varnish ignoring a backend

Tags: varnish, varnishncsa

I have varnish setup with 2 backend servers with a round-robin director.

The 2 backends are showing up in varnishstat and varnishadm as healthy.

varnishadm output:

```
Backend name                   Admin      Probe
boot.app1                      probe      Healthy 5/5
boot.app2                      probe      Healthy 5/5
```

VCL Configuration:

```
probe ping {
  .interval = 5s;
  .timeout = 1s;
  .threshold = 3;
  .window = 5;
  .url = "/ping";
}
backend app1 {
  .host = "app-1.example.com";
  .port = "80";
  .probe = ping;
}

backend app2 {
  .host = "app-2.example.com";
  .port = "80";
  .probe = ping;
}

new application_servers = directors.round_robin();
application_servers.add_backend(app1);
application_servers.add_backend(app2);

set req.backend_hint = application_servers;
```

varnishstat output:

```
VBE.boot.app1.happy                                                                                                                        ffffffffff     VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
VBE.boot.app1.bereq_hdrbytes                                                                                                                    66.17K         0.00         91.00          0.00          0.00          0.00
VBE.boot.app1.beresp_hdrbytes                                                                                                                   76.72K         0.00        106.00          0.00          0.00          0.00
VBE.boot.app1.beresp_bodybytes                                                                                                                  11.91M         0.00         16.50K         0.00          0.00          0.00
VBE.boot.app1.conn                                                                                                                                251          0.00           .          251.00        251.00        251.00
VBE.boot.app1.req                                                                                                                                 251          0.00           .            0.00          0.00          0.00
VBE.boot.app2.happy                                                                                                                        ffffffffff     VVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVVV
```

You can see from the varnishstat command that traffic appears to only be sent to the first server in the round-robin configuration. There's no other lines for the app2 server other than .happy

Any thoughts on what would be causing the director to pick the first server every time?

Comment: The Round-Robin method does not really equally check all metrics to see who is the most available server and send the request there. Round-robin simply randomly selects a server to send the request.

Comment: The round robin appears to always send the traffic to app1. app2 never receives any traffic

Comment: Is set req.backend_hint = application_servers; in sub vcl_recv {} ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your VCL file to something like this

```
probe ping {
   .interval = 5s;
   .timeout = 1s;
   .threshold = 3;
   .window = 5;
   .url = "/ping";
}
backend app1 {
   .host = "app-1.example.com";
   .port = "80";
   .probe = ping;
}

backend app2 {
   .host = "app-2.example.com";
   .port = "80";
   .probe = ping;
}

sub vcl_init {
    new application_servers = directors.round_robin();
    application_servers.add_backend(app1);
    application_servers.add_backend(app2);
}

sub vcl_recv{
    set req.backend_hint = application_servers;
}
```